# How to populate a text box with values from a derived class? C#

Tags: c#

In my form I have the following...

```
if (productNo == this.product1.ProductNumber)  //ProductNumber comes from Product class
                {
                    //if so, set the other values of the text boxes to that of the 
                    //product in memory
                    tbDescription.Text = product1.ProductDescription; //Works - from Product class
                    tbOnHand.Text = product1.NumberOnHand.ToString(); //Works - from Product class
                    tbUnitOfMeasure.Text = product1.UnitOfMeasure;    //Works - from Product class

                    tbVendorID.Text = product1.VendorID; // Doesn't work - from derived ManufacturedProduct class 
                }
```

Where VendorID comes from ManufacturedProduct class which is a derived class that comes from Product.  The last line of code is what doesn't work.  I want to be able to populate tbVendorID with the value in product1.VendorID (which by the way is an int)

I get the following error...Objects.Product' does not contain a definition for 'VendorID' and no extension method 'VendorID' accepting a first argument of type 'Objects.Product' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast it to `ManufacturedProduct` if you want to access properties of the child class:

```
ManufacturedProduct mfgProduct = (ManufacturedProduct) product1;
if (productNo == mfgProduct.ProductNumber)  
{
    tbDescription.Text = mfgProduct.ProductDescription;  
    tbOnHand.Text = mfgProduct.NumberOnHand.ToString();  
    tbUnitOfMeasure.Text = mfgProduct.UnitOfMeasure;    
    tbVendorID.Text = mfgProduct.VendorID;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
if (productNo == this.product1.ProductNumber)  //ProductNumber comes from Product class
{
        tbDescription.Text = product1.ProductDescription; 
        tbOnHand.Text = product1.NumberOnHand.ToString(); 
        tbUnitOfMeasure.Text = product1.UnitOfMeasure;    
        if(priduct1 is ManufacturedProduct)
               tbVendorID.Text = ((ManufacturedProduct)product1).VendorID.ToString(); 
}
```

Comment: This underlines VerndorID and gives the same error.  :-(   Any ideas?

Comment: Just add `ToString()` call on VendorID